# Zend Framework - Zend_Auth::getInstance() causes 500 error

Tags: zend-framework, lamp

I've recently moved an in-development Zend Framework application over to a production server to test the setup.

Irregardless of application environment and file permissions, the application throws a 500 error. After manual debugging, I've narrowed down the culprit to calling `Zend_Auth::getInstance();` in `application/Bootstrap.php`.

Relevant function:

```
protected function _initAutoLoad() {
    $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
    ));

    $acl = new Model_Acl();
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance(); //<- this line breaks

    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontController->registerPlugin(new Plugin_AccessCheck($acl, $auth));

    return $modelLoader;
}
```

Development environment is running PHP 5.3.8 on Mac OS X, and the server is running PHP 5.3.10 on Ubuntu 11.10 Server.

I've tried applying the same PHP settings on the server, and the error persists. I think it's probably a path permission, but I haven't run into this problem before and Google's not being particularly helpful.

If I try to `echo` or `var_dump` anything before the `Zend_Auth` call, I get results. Anything after that is ineffective and the server instead just returns a vanilla 500 error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what's the storage type and auth adapter for Zend_Auth? Maybe, it is failing while trying to get access to the Session (the default auth storage) or the adapter?

Comment: Can you tell if the 500 error is generated by Zend and a stack trace and exception message is present or is it a problem with the server configuration and maybe something is in your Apache server error log?

Comment: Not getting anything in Apache's error logs, and I can run simpler PHP applications with no problems. I'm using the LDAP Zend_Auth adapter, and Zend isn't giving a stack trace. I'll have to dig further in and find more tomorrow. php.ini is set to log to it's own file, and this isn't giving me anything useful either.

Comment: What's your IDE? If it's Zend Studio, you can try to debug your application using the Debug perspective and see where exactly your application breaks.

Comment: Writing in vim, but someone else has tried debugging in Netbeans with xdebug and gotten nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this

```
Zend_Session::start();
```

before

```
   $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
```

So final code

```
protected function _initAutoLoad() {
    $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
    ));
Zend_Session::start();
    $acl = new Model_Acl();
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance(); //<- this line breaks

    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontController->registerPlugin(new Plugin_AccessCheck($acl, $auth));

    return $modelLoader;
}
```

If this doesn't solve then open index.php (inside public dir) and do

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));
```

This will bring your application in development mode then full error will appear simply post it here .

Comment: Closer. Now I'm getting debug errors: `'The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded'`. I've already got  `extension=php_pdo_mysql.so` in my php.ini file, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Additionally, according to `phpinfo()`, another config file at `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini` is being parsed, which contains `extension=pdo_mysql.so`.

Comment: Resolved the new problem, my `php.ini` was pointing to an incorrect extension path. Thanks for the help.